# trying to add onSnapshot option to Get realtime updates firebase reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i'm trying to add onSnapshot option to my code, i put a console log with data, In this simple code is working:

```
db.collection("cities")
    .doc(cid)
    .onSnapshot(function(doc) {
        console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
    });
```

So, now how can i add this functionality to the following code:

```
 getCityByID = (cid) => {
        db.collection("cities")
            .doc(cid)
            .get()
            .then((doc) => {
                if (doc.exists) {
                    this.setState(
                        {
                            city: doc.data(),
                        },
                        () => {
                            this.setState({
                                isLoaded: true,
                            });
                        }
                    );
                } else {
                    this.props.history.push({ pathname: "/" });
                }
            });
    };
```

any suggestion please. thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

ohh! i found a solution, i don't know if is the correct way, but its works.

```
db.collection("cities")
            .doc(cid)
            .onSnapshot((doc) => {
                this.setState(
                    {
                        city: doc.data(),
                    },
                    () => {
                        this.setState({
                            isLoaded: true,
                        });
                    }
                );
            });
```